# JavaScript not firing in header or footer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm running a simple on scroll event to see if my JavaScript is firing, but it doesn't do anything whether it's in the header of footer?

**header.php**

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/src/js/load-more.js"></script> 
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

**footer.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/src/js/load-more.js"></script>
```

**load-more.js**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
       alert("near bottom!");
   }
});
```

Ideas? Am I missing something oblivious?

Comment: Have you checked your *rendered* html to see where php has stuffed your code?  You could also try wrapping `$(window).scroll` inside `$(document).ready(function() { $(winodw).scroll...`.

Comment: Easiest way to check if your external .js file is loading is to put `alert("load-more")` at the very top of the file (as the first line).  Or you could check the browser network tab and console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it works, the problems may one of this:

- You are using the $ selector, which is defined by the JQuery library, so you need to include JQuery before your script, otherwise it will result in an error as the "$" selector will not be defined.
- You are not scrolling enough to trigger the if condition, which seems strange to me, but without seeing your HTML page i cannot tell.

So, in my opinion option 1 seems the most likely, open the developer console in your browser and see if the javascript throws any error.